# Calling a method of One View controller from Another View Controller

Tags: iphone, methods, uiviewcontroller

I have a method "someMethod" declared in OneViewController.h

```
@interface OneViewController
{
UIView *tempView;
..

}
-(void) someMethod ;
@end
```

and implemented in OneViewController.m file

```
@implementation OneViewController

-(void) someMethod 
{
tempView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 200, 250)];
tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
if([[self.view subviews] containsObject:tempView])
[tempView removeFromSuperView];
   else
   [self.view addsubview:tempView];

}
```

I want to call *someMethod* when present at different viewController - secondViewController

(something like `[OneViewController someMethod]`), So that when I get back to OneViewController I can see the changes made by *someMethod*.

Do I need to use appDelegate methods?

I have tried following but it doesn't work.

```
neViewController *newViewController = [[OneViewController alloc] init];
[newViewController someMethod];
```

Thanks for any help in advance..

Comment: are you moving to secondviewcontroller from oneviewcontroller? and want to access oneviewcontroller method from secondviewcontroller right?

Comment: yes. I am moving from OneviewController to SecondViewController. and want to access OneViewController Method from SecondViewController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the SecondViewController, declare a reference for OneViewController class. You can have assign property. Set the reference before you move to SecondViewController. Now with the reference, you can call the instance method `[_oneView someMethod]`.

**Edit:**

Declare

```
OneViewController *_oneView;
```

Also add the assign property,

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) OneViewController *_oneView;
```

Synthesize the variable in .m file.

While showing the SecondViewController from OneViewController, just add the following line.

```
secondView._oneView = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Lanc. But how can I create reference for OneViewController in SecondViewController?

Comment: Thanks a lot Lanc. It worked perfectly (I don't know why)....!!! I need to study passing reference and delegates methods in detail.

Answer (score 2):

sometimes calling a method directlry creating `[classObject methodName]` does not refelect the changes in views. Like if you want to change a `UIScrollView` property from `scrollEnble = NO;` to `scrollEnable = YES;`, it does not refelect.
You should use singleton of `UIApplication`.

Suppose you want to call `ViewController1'`s method `- (void)myMethod` in `ViewController2` then here are the steps:

- In you AppDelegate import `ViewController1` and create its object `*vc`. Delare property `@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController1 *vc;`. `synthesize` also.
- Now come to `Viewcontroller1` class. Import `AppDelegate.h` in you `Viewcontroller1`'s and in `viewDidLoad` write like this:

  `AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   appDelegate.vc1 = self;`
- Go to your `ViewController2.h` and import `AppDelegate.h`
- Go to the line where you want to call `ViewController2`'s method and write like this:

  `AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   [[appDelegate vc1] myMethod]; // to allow scrolling`

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should create a protocol and delegate methods to accomplish what you are looking for.

Create a protocol, implement it in secondViewController and set the protocol delegate to firstViewController and then use the delegate methods for invoking the relevant methods in secondViewController

I hope it works for you..!!

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing it is to change the declaration to `+(void) someMethod ;` in your OneViewController.h and change the minus to a plus correspondingly in the implementation file. This will make it a class-method and not an instance method. Then in your SecondViewController.m file, make sure to put `@class OneViewController;` before the implementation declaration; then you can call [OneViewController someMethod] and it should execute. Cheers!

Comment: Changing sign from - to + gives error while compiling, says instance variable accessed in class method.